# What does it mean when a thread moves out of an object's monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading

All I want to know is that when a thread enters out of a lock, does it means it "ends" or just that it has finished using that function or code which employed the use of the object whose monitor that particular thread is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just that it has finished using that function or code which employed the use of the object. Such pieces of code are commonly known as [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)(s).

Comment: It would be easier to explain, if you place your code in the question. At least the lines where the loop starts and ends and where you enter and leave the monitor.

Comment: Actually it was general question bugging me. Like for example, one thread finishes using a function, then would that thread use it again or another thread use it in the meantime.. And the function is synchronized

Comment: If a `synchronized` function is being called inside a for loop, the thread gets exclusive access to the function for each iteration of the loop, so the thread is out of the critical section as soon as the function ends. However, if there is a for loop with in a `synchronized` function, then the thread comes out of the critical section once the for loop or whole of the function body ends.

Comment: what do you mean by "the thread has exclusive access to the function only for that function"

Comment: i understood the better part of things, thanks! just clarify that statement

Comment: It means no other thread will have access to the `synchronized` code except the one which got access to it. Conversely, if another thread is using it, this thread will have to "wait" for the other thread to finish.

Answer (score 0):

For your general understanding: methods run on threads. So it is possible that one method is being executed by multiple threads at the same time.

Imagine you want to make sure that a method, or part of it, can only be executed by one thread at a time. This is called a critical section.

A critical section in Java can be protected by a lock: implicitly via [synchronized](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) or explicitly via [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html).

Only one thread at a time can acquire the lock and entering the critical section requires that the lock be acquired first. At the end of the critical section the lock is released and the thread continues running but now without holding that lock.

A thread encountering a lock held by another thread (not necessarily for the same critical section) cannot proceed at that point and must wait. The thread, and other threads waiting on the same lock, will be notified when they can retry to acquire the lock. Again, only one thread will win and the process repeats (unless you have a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) for example).